# JPA string comparison

Tags: string, jpa, comparison, equals, jpql

I've written a simple login system using a JPQL query, which always returns no result:

```
public boolean check(String name, String password) {
    final String qstring="SELECT e FROM Muser e WHERE e.name = '"+name+"'";
    Muser user;
    try{
        user = em.createQuery(qstring, Muser.class).getSingleResult();  
    }
    catch(NoResultException e){
        return false;
    }
    return password.equals(user.getPassword());
}
```

When I changed it to a native query:

```
user = (Muser) em.createNativeQuery(qstring, Muser.class).getSingleResult();
```

or an int expression:

```
final String qstring="SELECT e FROM Muser e WHERE e.id = "+id;
```

It goes all right. What's the problem? Thanks a million!

Comment: Do not store passwords in clear text: hash them. Do create the query which arguments in it: use parameters (to avoid code injection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be a problem with string comparison in your JPA provider. Do you test it on the case-sensitive data?

You could also try (and it's the preferred way) **using parameters** instead of crafting your statement by hand. It's not only **safer** (prevents SQL injection) but also **faster**: not only for Java (you don't concatenate Strings) but also for the DB (the query can be prepared once for all executions). It might be something like this:

```
final String qstring = "SELECT e FROM Muser e WHERE e.name = :name";
TypedQuery<Muser> query = em.createQuery(qstring, Muser.class);
query.setParameter("name", name);
user = query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I've tried all possibilities:using parameters, changing different implementations(EclipseLink and Hibernate) while the string is EXACTLY the same as in DB, but it doesn't work still...

Comment: @user1036998 how is your entity defined? How is the field 'name' annotated (or defined in orm.xml)? What is the column in the database defined?

Comment: @Id
 @Column(name = "NAME", length = 12)
 public String getName() {
  return this.name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 } Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ArchBuddhiCat are you using JPA to generate your DB schema, or you work on prepared one? Could you post how is the databse column defined? What value are you passing as a 'name' parameter?

Comment: I created a table called MUSER in an Oracle database first, and then defined the entity. The name column is defined as CHAR type with a length of 12. I'll try deleting the table and letting JPA create the table automatically later on.The name parameter is passed from an EJB bean which is called by a JSF page.

Comment: Ok, give a sign if jpa-created table would solve anything, and meanwhile - could you check what sql is generated from your jpql query? Check your jpa provider documentation for information how to print these data.

Comment: Eventually succeeded! I set the properties in persistence.xml and the SQL query displayed in the server log. When I was using EclipseLink, the query seemed right:SELECT NAME, BALANCE, PASSWORD FROM MUSER WHERE (NAME = ?) with a parameter bound, but it returned no results. So I updated a Hibernate addon for my Glassfish and regenerated the table, and it worked! Hibernate is really robust and mature. Thank you for being so patient! Shall we make friends?

Comment: Sure. I still wonder what was wrong in this case :) glad you have it working.

Comment: @PiotrNowicki do you know how to test inequality ? !=:name doesn't seem  to work.

Comment: @Ced and what about `<>`?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki Doesn't work either. Did you have success with <> ? I wonder if that not equal is the root of the problem. However just equals work.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is because of String comparison.My solution to this problem is:

using lowercase for comparison.

```
final String qstring = "SELECT e FROM Muser e WHERE LOWER(e.name) = :name";
TypedQuery<Muser> query = em.createQuery(qstring, Muser.class);
query.setParameter("name", name.toLowerCase());
user = query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I'd use "WHERE LOWER(e.name) = LOWER(:name)" and avoid doing name.toLowerCase() in Java. Keep everything in one place, i.e. Separation of Concerns (SoC).